# MongoDB find by max value in array of documents

Tags: mongodb

Given a collection with documents such as:

```
{
    "host" : "example.com",
    "ips" : [
        {
            "ip" : NumberLong("1111111111"),
            "timestamp" : NumberLong(1373970044)
        },
        {
            "ip" : NumberLong("2222222222"),
            "timestamp" : NumberLong(1234978746)
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to return all documents with an ip value of X, but only if the associated timestamp for X is the *highest* timestamp in the ips array (so the above example document should **not** match a search for "2222222222" because that is *not* the IP with the most recent timestamp).

This is my first time doing anything much beyond fairly basic stuff in MongoDB so the closest I've been able to get is:

> coll.aggregate({$match:{"ips.ip":X}},{$group:{"_id":"$host",
>   "max":{$max:"$ips.timestamp"}}},{$sort:{"ips.timestamp":-1}}).result

Which obviously doesn't give me what I'm looking for, it returns anything with an ips.ip value of X. How do I return only documents where ip.ip is X only if X's associated timestamp is the highest for that ips array?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If `host` is unique, the following code should do the job. Otherwise, you can simply replace `host` by `_id` in the grouping operation:

```
coll.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$ips"},
  {$project:{host:"$host",ip:"$ips.ip", ts:"$ips.timestamp"} },
  {$sort:{ts:1} },
  {$group: {_id: "$host", IPOfMaxTS:{$last: "$ip"}, ts:{$last: "$ts"} } }
])
```

Comment: Disregard above comment, I was on the right track I just foolishly put the match in the wrong place, placing `$match:{"IPOfMaxTS":X}}` _after_ the group operation gives me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks, this $unwind function worked for a similar problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$reduce` in aggregation pipeline starting from mongo 3.4 version

```
db.t64.aggregate([
    {$addFields : {ips : {$reduce : {
        input : "$ips", 
        initialValue : {timestamp : 0}, 
        in : {$cond: [{$gte : ["$$this.timestamp", "$$value.timestamp"]},"$$this", "$$value"]}}
    }}}
])
```

sample collection

```
> db.t64.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c45e00f328877e101354d97"),
        "host" : "example.com",
        "ips" : [
                {
                        "ip" : NumberLong(1111111111),
                        "timestamp" : NumberLong(1373970044)
                },
                {
                        "ip" : NumberLong("2222222222"),
                        "timestamp" : NumberLong(1234978746)
                }
        ]
}
```

output

```
> db.t64.aggregate([ {$addFields : {ips : {$reduce : { input : "$ips",  initialValue : {timestamp : 0},  in : {$cond: [{$gte : ["$$this.timestamp", "$$value.timestamp"]},"$$this", "$$value"]}} }}} ])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c45e00f328877e101354d97"), "host" : "example.com", "ips" : { "ip" : NumberLong(1111111111), "timestamp" : NumberLong(1373970044) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

**IN Simple Words** , 
if you have **mongo query Response** something like below -
and you want only highest value from **Array->  "Date"**

```
{
  "_id": "57ee5a708e117c754915a2a2",
  "TotalWishs": 3,
  "Events": [
    "57f805c866bf62f12edb8024"
  ],
  "wish": [
    "Cosmic Eldorado  Mountain Bikes, 26-inch (Grey/White)",
    "Asics Men's Gel-Nimbus 18 Black, Snow and Fiery Red Running Shoes - 10 UK/India (45 EU) (11 US)",
    "Suunto Digital Black Dial Unisex Watch - SS018734000"
  ],
  "Date": [
    "2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "2017-03-05T00:00:00.000Z"
  ],
  "UserDetails": [
    {
      "createdAt": "2016-09-30T12:28:32.773Z",
      "jeenesFriends": [
        "57edf8a96ad8f6ff453a384a",
        "57ee516c8e117c754915a26b",
        "58a1644b6c91d2af783770b0",
        "57ef4631b97d81824cf54795"
      ],
      "userImage": "user_profile/Male.png",
      "email": "roopak@small-screen.com",
      "fullName": "Roopak Kapoor"
    }
  ],

},
```

***Then you have add

> Latest_Wish_CreatedDate: { $max: "$Date"},

somthing like below-

```
{ 
                $project : { _id: 1,
                             TotalWishs : 1 ,
                              wish:1 ,
                               Events:1, 
                               Wish_CreatedDate:1,
                               Latest_Wish_CreatedDate: { $max: "$Date"},
                            } 
            }
```

**And Final Query Response will be below**

```
{
  "_id": "57ee5a708e117c754915a2a2",
  "TotalWishs": 3,
  "Events": [
    "57f805c866bf62f12edb8024"
  ],
  "wish": [
    "Cosmic Eldorado  Mountain Bikes, 26-inch (Grey/White)",
    "Asics Men's Gel-Nimbus 18 Black, Snow and Fiery Red Running Shoes - 10 UK/India (45 EU) (11 US)",
    "Suunto Digital Black Dial Unisex Watch - SS018734000"
  ],
  "Wish_CreatedDate": [
    "2017-03-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    "2017-02-13T00:00:00.000Z"
  ],
  "UserDetails": [
    {
      "createdAt": "2016-09-30T12:28:32.773Z",
      "jeenesFriends": [
        "57edf8a96ad8f6ff453a384a",
        "57ee516c8e117c754915a26b",
        "58a1644b6c91d2af783770b0",
        "57ef4631b97d81824cf54795"
      ],
      "userImage": "user_profile/Male.png",
      "email": "roopak@small-screen.com",
      "fullName": "Roopak Kapoor"
    }
  ],
  "Latest_Wish_CreatedDate": "2017-03-05T00:00:00.000Z"
},
```